# pyautogui .locateOnScreen() not working in Lubuntu Virtualbox machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, python-idle, pyautogui

Good evening,
I'm struggling to get the pyautogui.locateOnScreen function to work.  I am using a Lubuntu virtual machine in virtual box and I have disabled mouse integration. I have tried with scaled mode on and off.  I am using IDLE.  Each time I get nothing returned, not even 'None', which from my web research should be the answer if the function ran and did not find the image.  Here is some sample code I have been using to try and get it to work and what I get back in the IDE:

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.screenshot('ScreenShot2.png')
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=1280x720 at 0x7F1D44D14518>
>>> pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ScreenShot2.png')
>>>
```

Is there something simple I am missing or are there any know limitations with this virtual set up?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like locateOnScreen does not work with jpg files, but it works when I take a sample of a screen shot and save it as a png file.  I expected it to display (0,0,1280,720) when I searched for a full screen shot, so I don't really understand the behaviour above and it also threw me that it did not display a 'None' result when it didn't find anything.
Other than that, I think I have managed to solve the basic issue myself.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about pyautogui, but if the function returns None, then nothing should be printed in interactive mode when echoing the value of an expression statement.  `None` reprensents 'no value', so nothing is printed.  The output you pasted is correct. To see `None`, one must use print.

```
>>> None
>>> print(None)
None
```

Comment: Thanks. That explains why I was getting nothing back. I've also just realised my own blunder when searching for the screen shot. Typing the code to search for the image meant that the screen no longer matched the screen shot *face palm*. So I guess the way I know it has worked, but found nothing is when I get no result and no error message. If it hasn't worked there should be an error message. Do you know of a way I can get it to explicitly tell me there is no result? Thanks